# Reassigning CComBSTR, memory leak?

Tags: c++, mfc, com, atl, bstr

As it's written in the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccombstr-class?view=msvc-160#operator_eq) CComBSTR::operator= creates a copy of src.
So when I write

```
someCComBSTR = std::to_wstring(someVal).c_str();
```

I will have a copy of the temporary and everything is ok. But I haven't found what happens with the previous value, will it be freed or rewritten, or I first should manually empty my CComBSTR object?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the 'temporary'. The version of the `=` operator you are using is taking an `LPCSTR` as its argument and assigning a copy of that to the `m_str` member of your destination `BSTR` object. Presumably, that will be freed when `someCComBSTR` is destroyed.

Comment: if the class is not broken you can assume that it correctly manages its resources. Did you observe some memory leak? Kind of relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: @463 Visual Studio comes with several `BSTR` wrappers (`CComBSTR`, `_bstr_t`, etc.). They all behave slightly different with respect to resource management. Making assumptions is terrible advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CComBSTR` is defined in the header *atlcomcli.h* in Visual Studio's *atlmfc/include* directory. All assignment operators (`operator=`) release the currently owned data by calling [`SysFreeString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-sysfreestring) (with some exceptions that aren't interesting here).

The line of code posted in the question will not leak any resources. It is invoking the following assignment operator for `CComBSTR` (comments added for clarity):

```cpp
CComBSTR& operator=(_In_opt_z_ LPCOLESTR pSrc)
{
    // Prevent self-assignment
    if (pSrc != m_str)
    {
        // Free currently owned resources
        ::SysFreeString(m_str);
        if (pSrc != NULL)
        {
            // Create copy of pSrc and take ownership
            m_str = ::SysAllocString(pSrc);
            // Error handling
            if (!*this)
            {
                AtlThrow(E_OUTOFMEMORY);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Clear instance data if pSrc is a null pointer
            m_str = NULL;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```